# Rails - "objectvalue" is an invalid value for property "object" with type "Reference"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am having a rails app in which i have to generate a custom open graph story say `Peter fought his friend using appname` by having `fought` action and `friend` object.

Here's what i did.

In javascript

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: AppIDhere, // App ID
            status: true,    // check login status
            cookie: true,    // enable cookies to allow the
                             // server to access the session
            xfbml: true,     // parse page for xfbml or html5
            // social plugins like login button below
            version: 'v2.0',  // Specify an API version
        });
        // Put additional init code here
    };
```

For loading Javascript SDK

```
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And the function on clicking share button

```
function postStory() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'share_open_graph',
            action_type: 'appNamespace:fought',
            action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                object: 'site_url',
                friend: "friendname"
            })
        }, function (response) {
            if (!response || response.error || response.id == undefined) {
                //alert('Error occured');
            } else {
                alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
            }
        });
}
```

And the meta tags used

```
<meta property='fb:app_id' content='appID'/>
  <meta property="og:type" content="appNamespace:friend">
  <meta property='og:url' content='site_url'/>
  <meta property='og:title' content='OG title'/>
  <meta property='og:image' content='google_image_url'/>
```

But i am getting this strange error

`"friendname" is an invalid value for property "friend" with type "Reference"`

I can't find what is wrong in here.
Any help here is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring `pageURL` points to a page where `<meta property="og:type" content="appNamespace:friend">`, try:

```
  action_properties: JSON.stringify({
    'friend': {
      'og:url': pageURL,
      'og:type': 'appNamespace:friend',
      'og:title': 'Test title',
      'appNamespace:friendname': 'Some name here',
    },
  })
```